# PrimeReact - data table inline row editing

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am using PrimeReact Data table which works perfectly fine when I use built-in edit button for inline row editing. But I would like to customize the editor buttons e.g. I would like to display edit and delete button in same column which is currently not supported out of box, therefore I need to customize the row-editor column.

I would like to perform an editing action as PrimeReact is doing here https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/datatable/edit/ but from my custom component e.g. button I am not able to do that. The issue I am having is when I capture the click event on my custom component I am not able to get grid's data or any react state variable within that event handler, hence not able to perform editing.

Anyone know how to do that?

**Please do not share CRUD example from PrimeReact because I do not want to use dialog I want inline row editing on the table.**

Comment: I think you would have to submit a feature request on GitHub to allow calling the Edit Row function dynamically from outside the table.